# How to understand error log

Tags: plugins, wordpress, error-logging

Our information site (WP) has suddenlly stopped working, and the the error log looks as below. However, I have troubles reading this log... What could be problem with our site?

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/wp-content/plugins
/google-maps-ready/modules/options/mod.php on line 13 Notice: Undefined index: save_statistic
 in /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/wp-content/plugins/google-maps-ready/modules
/options/mod.php on line 14 Deprecated: Non-static method frameGmp::isAdminPlugPage() should
 not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /customers/c/6/0
/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/wp-content/plugins/google-maps-ready/modules/templates/mod.php
 on line 18 Deprecated: Non-static method frameGmp::isAdminPlugPage() should not be called
statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/
info/wp-content/plugins/google-maps-ready/modules/templates/mod.php on line 49 Deprecated:
Non-static method frameGmp::isAdminPlugPage() should not be called statically,
assuming $this from incompatible context in /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/
wp-content/plugins/google-maps-ready/modules/gmap/mod.php on line 4 Deprecated: Non-static
method frameGmp::isAdminPlugPage() should not be called statically, assuming $this from
incompatible context in /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/wp-content/plugins/
google-maps-ready/modules/marker_groups/mod.php on line 4 Deprecated: Non-static method
frameGmp::isAdminPlugPage() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible
context in /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/wp-content/plugins/google-maps-ready
/modules/icons/mod.php on line 6 Notice: Undefined index: sh-adminbar-hide in /customers
/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/wp-content/plugins/showhide-adminbar/showhide-adminbar.php
on line 23 Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already
sent (output started at /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/wp-content/plugins/
google-maps-ready/modules/options/mod.php:13) in /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info
/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/ninja-forms.php on line 624 Warning: Cannot modify header
information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd
.www/info/wp-content/plugins/google-maps-ready/modules/options/mod.php:13) in
/customers/c/6/0/xxxxxx/httpd.www/info/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121
```

Answer (score 0):

it's problem in configuration in "google maps ready" plugin plz make it disable and check otherwise check it's configuration.

Comment: Disabled Google maps ready and some errors disappeared. The remaining errors refered to another plugin which I disabled as well. Now no errors turns up but instead the site times out... What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you been looking at it?